Create modal using intercepting and parallel routes in Nextjs 14
I have recently started a project where I am trying to create a social media website which renders the users' posts and users can comment on them. I am using Nextjs 14 and am using the app route. Instead of sending my complex project, I will include a simple example, so please ignore styling and formatting.
Root page.tsx - includes the title of the page and a button that redirects to the homepage
Home route - page.tsx - includes the title of the page and a button that opens the modal. When the modal is open the url changes to /compose/post
@modal/(.)/compose/post - page.tsx - includes the title of the modal and the close button that redirects the user back to the home page.
At the moment it all works okay. The only issue is that when I refresh the page when the modal is open (/compose/post), then the page renders a 404. I think this is related to adding a default.tsx page that returns null. I have done this, but it is still not working.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
This is my file structure
src/
  app/
    @modal/
      default.tsx
    .(compose)/
      post/
        page.tsx
        default.tsx
    home/
      page.tsx
      default.tsx
    globals.css
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx

Here is the Github link.
Here is the code for each file that is relevant:
//src/app/page.tsx

"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    router.push("home");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>I am the root page</div>
      <button style={{ background: "blue" }} onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Go to homepage
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

//src/app/layout.tsx

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Intercepting and Parallel Routes",
  description: "Experimenting",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  modal,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  modal: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {modal}
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

//src/app/default.tsx

import Page from "./page";
export default Page;

//src/app/home/page.tsx

"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleOnClick = () => {
      router.push("compose/post");
    };
    return( 
        <>
       <div>I am the homepage</div>
            <button style={{ background: "blue" }} onClick={handleOnClick}>
                Open modal
            </button>
        </>
    )
   }

//src/app/@modal/page.tsx

export default function Page() {
  return null;
}

//src/app/@modal/default.tsx

export default function Default() {
  return null;
}

//src/app/@modal/(.)compose/post/page.tsx

"use client";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function ComposePost() {
   const router = useRouter();
   const handleClose = () => {
      router.back();
    };
 return( 
   <>
      <div>I am the modal</div>
      <button style={{background: 'green'}}onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
   </>
 )
}


The modal is the first part of the parallel route. next expects an ~/app/compose/post directory to route to when you refresh.
This route is the second part of the parallel route and should include the whole of the part that you display in your modal.

if you're trying to make modal that is only used to write posts then you shouldn't use parallel routing for it. just add a modal to your home page.

thank you for your reply. To your first point if I create a separate directory for compose/post, then the page just shows the modal and not the homepage behind it. What should I include in the page.tsx in the /compose/post so that this doesn’t happen?
And for your second point, the thing is I need the modal to have a different url to the homepage when it is open. That’s why I want to use intercepting and parallel routes. I am doing a similar concept to the X (Twitter) homepage. Any thoughts? Thanks again ☺️
